# Adicionar 0.1 num setInterval dá problemas de arredondamento

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um `setInterval` a correr a cada segundo que chama uma função `myTimer` que adiciona 0.1 a um valor total e mostra no ecrã.

É suposto ir 0.1->0.2->0.3->0.4->0.5->...

Mas está a ir 0.1->0.2000004->0.3->0.4->0.49999999->0.6->... (exemplo, não faz sempre os mesmos arredondamentos e nos mesmos instantes)

Não está a fazer a conta certa, anda a adicionar arredondamentos de 0.1 por vezes.

**Codigo:**

```
<div id="total"></div>
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
var total = 0;
function myTimer() {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
        total = total + 0.1;
    }
</script>
```

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/se2xt9ma/1/

Alguma forma de corrigir este erro ou alguma razão para estar a acontecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo de um método que você pode usar:

**.toFixed()**

```
<div id="total">
</div>

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
var total = 0;
function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(1);
    total = total + 0.1;
}
```

O .toFixed() converte um número para uma string, neste caso, com **1** decimal.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/1Lhm7qjf/

Comment: Tinha tentado adicionar ```total = total.toFixed(1) ;``` mas não fazia as contas, não sabia que convertia em String. Obrigado pela solução.

Comment: De nada @Pbras :)

Answer (score 1):

Isso é normal, a causa disso é que ponto flutuante é representado internamente em binário, e 0.1 é uma dizima periódica em binário. Algumas soluções simples que você pode adotar:

1) incrementar 'total' de 1 em 1, dividindo por 10 apenas na hora de exibir ou usar o valor.

2) incrementar por um valor fracionário que tenha representação exata em binário, por exemplo 0.125. Neste caso você teria de mudar o ritmo do timer para 125ms, também.