# Ajuda em python Listas

Tags: python-3.x, lista, matriz, data, data-manipulation

Boa noite estou tendo dificuldades com isto:

```
[['1', 0.0, 1.8], ['1', 3.0, 2.0], ['1', 5.0, 1.5], ['1', 6.0, 1.5], ['1', 9.0, 3.0], ['2', 0.0, 1.8], ['2', 1.0, 1.5], ['2', 2.0, 1.5], ['2', 3.0, 2.0], ['2', 8.0, 2.1], ['3', 0.0, 1.8], ['3', 1.0, 2.0], ['3', 4.0, 1.5], ['3', 8.0, 1.5], ['3', 9.0, 1.5], ['4', 0.0, 1.8], ['4', 1.0, 1.5], ['4', 2.0, 2.0], ['4', 3.0, 2.0], ['4', 4.0, 2.0]]
```

quero encontrar os valores das filas iguais e achar as medias aritméticas dos outros dois valores..

a saída do meu código deve ser assim

```
[['1',4.6,1.96],['2',2.8,1.78],['3',4.4,1.66],['4',2,1.86]]
```

por exemplo para os valores da `fila[0]==1`, para achar a media destes valores deve se somar os valores `(0.0+3.0+5.0+6.0+9.0)` e dividir-los pela quantidade dos mesmos,5.
Não consigo percorrer da forma correta esta matriz para fazer a condição certa para achar a matriz resultado...

Recorri a primeira lista com este código mas so consigo achar as medias dos valore que contem como primeiro elemento ao `str '1'...`

```
suma = 0

lista2=[]

for n in range (len(lista)-1):

    if lista[n][0]==lista[n][0]:

        lista2.append(lista[n][0])

        suma= suma+lista[n][1]

    if lista[n][0]!=lista[n+1][0]:

        break

print (suma)

#print(len(lista2))

print(suma/len(lista2))
```

Comment: tem que ser dessa forma?

Comment: sim o resultado tem estar na forma de lista de listas de novo, ou seja como uma matriz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O teste que você fez não tem sentido:

```
if lista[n][0]==lista[n][0]:
```

Esta condição verifica se o elemento é igual a ele próprio, que sempre será. Quando faz `if lista[n][0]!=lista[n+1][0]:` está a assumir que os elementos iguais estão sempre seguidos e se não estiverem também não iria funcionar. Para além disso não remove os duplicados e faz uma comparação inválida quando estiver no ultimo elemento.

Uma solução para o seu problema é agrupar os valores com base na primeira posição de cada elemento para um dicionario. Depois de agrupado calcula as medias de cada um e pode usar esse dicionario ou converter de volta numa lista.

Exemplo:

```
lista = [['1', 0.0, 1.8], ['1', 3.0, 2.0], ['1', 5.0, 1.5], ['1', 6.0, 1.5], ['1', 9.0, 3.0], ['2', 0.0, 1.8], ['2', 1.0, 1.5], ['2', 2.0, 1.5], ['2', 3.0, 2.0], ['2', 8.0, 2.1], ['3', 0.0, 1.8], ['3', 1.0, 2.0], ['3', 4.0, 1.5], ['3', 8.0, 1.5], ['3', 9.0, 1.5], ['4', 0.0, 1.8], ['4', 1.0, 1.5], ['4', 2.0, 2.0], ['4', 3.0, 2.0], ['4', 4.0, 2.0]]

agrupadas = {}
for elem in lista:
    fila = elem[0]
    if fila in agrupadas: # se já existe no dicionario acrescenta os numeros
        agrupadas[fila][1].append(elem[1])
        agrupadas[fila][2].append(elem[2])
    else: # se não existe cria uma nova entrada
        agrupadas[fila] = [fila, [elem[1]], [elem[2]]]

resultado = []
for item in agrupadas.values():
    # acrescenta o elemento à lista de resultado com os cálculos das médias
    resultado.append([item[0], sum(item[1])/len(item[1]), sum(item[2])/len(item[2])])

print(resultado)
```

Resultado:

```
[['1', 4.6, 1.9600000000000002], ['2', 2.8, 1.78], ['3', 4.4, 1.6600000000000001], ['4', 2.0, 1.86]]
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/B7TGIV)

O motivo pelo qual aparece 1.9600000000000002 em vez de 1.96 tem a ver com a falta de precisão na representação de valores de virgula flutuante, tal como o valor 0.1. Já existem várias perguntas aqui no site sobre esse tema, as quais sugiro a leitura:

- [Por que (0.1 + 0.2) + 0.3 é diferente de 0.1 + (0.2 + 0.3)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154189/por-que-0-1-0-2-0-3-%C3%A9-diferente-de-0-1-0-2-0-3)
- [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-c%C3%A1lculo-com-n%C3%BAmeros-quebrados)
- [Adicionar 0.1 num setInterval dá problemas de arredondamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/385503/adicionar-0-1-num-setinterval-d%C3%A1-problemas-de-arredondamento)

Para o seu caso talvez queria arredondar a duas casas decimais ou apenas mostrar o valor com duas casas decimais quando o for apresentar na saída.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Diferente do que você estava fazendo utilizando `for`, minha sugestão é utilizar o `pandas` que já tem algumas funções que vão facilitar seu trabalho. segue um exemplo de como ficaria o código. no final ele retorna a lista

```
import pandas as pd


l = [['1', 0.0, 1.8], ['1', 3.0, 2.0], ['1', 5.0, 1.5], ['1', 6.0, 1.5], ['1', 9.0, 3.0], ['2', 0.0, 1.8], ['2', 1.0, 1.5], ['2', 2.0, 1.5], ['2', 3.0, 2.0], ['2', 8.0, 2.1], ['3', 0.0, 1.8], ['3', 1.0, 2.0], ['3', 4.0, 1.5], ['3', 8.0, 1.5], ['3', 9.0, 1.5], ['4', 0.0, 1.8], ['4', 1.0, 1.5], ['4', 2.0, 2.0], ['4', 3.0, 2.0], ['4', 4.0, 2.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=l)

df = df.groupby([0]).mean()

df = df.reset_index()

df[2] = df[2].apply(lambda x : float("%.2f" %x))

listaFinal = df.values.tolist()

print(listaFinal)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!